# How to enable IPv6 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ipv6, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to enable IPv6 support on ubuntu 20.04 with no success

most resources i find online involve adding the following lines to  /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 0
```

which i did, with no effect

or editting  /etc/network/interfaces but this file does not exist on my system and i happen to have  /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml   i'm knew to netplan and cloud-init stuff. but when i opened the /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml  it says the file is generated and any modification will be overwritten.

now how am I supposed to enable it IPv6 ?  I don't need and IPv6 address, but i'm trying to install BigBlueButton 2.7 which is requiring IPv6 Support

Comment: IPv6 is enabled by default. What's the output of `ip a`?

Comment: @vidarlo turns out that in my case, it was not the case (rhymes :D)  `ip a | grep inet6` gave nothing. the answer below solved my issue.

Comment: Interesting. Upgrade from older installation, or admin disabled it by choice?

Comment: @vidarlo not sure, since it was a new VM, and admin was clueless...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file  `/etc/sysctl.conf` is used to persistently store kernel tuneables.

Any changes your make there will still need to be applied to your running kernel. That requires either:

- a reboot
- applying all settings defined in /etc/sysctl.conf with `[sudo] /sbin/sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`
- explicitly setting each of the correct kernel tuneables  individually  with for example

  - `[sudo] echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6`
  - or `[sudo] sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0`

Depending on how the system was further adjusted to (completely) disable IPv6 you may need to ensure that for example IPv6 is not also disabled at boot time in for example `/etc/default/grub` and/or that the correct kernel modules are loaded as well to support for example IPv6 firewall rules.

Comment: editing /etc/default/grub was exactly what i needed! now it works!